# Picture in odoo qweb report

Tags: image, report, odoo, qweb

I'd like show a picture in my qweb report.
When I copy i.e. from the website_quote modul to my xml file this line:
`<img src="/website_quote/static/src/img/partner_icon_01.png"/>`
it works fine, but if I copy the partner_icon_01.png file to my module directory, and change the line:
`<img src="/my_module/static/src/img/partner_icon_01.png"/>`, the picture doesn't appear in my report.
Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers: Janos

[image]

Comment: Have u try to check and print the report as the report type as HTML  and try to print again ?? tell me what is your result get ..??

Comment: You could see the report on my edited question. (the result mark withe black arrow)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code and check

```
 <img class="img img-responsive" src="/sale_order_report/static/src/img/header.jpg"/>
```

This will working fine from my side also follow the below link

[Click to See the Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561121/display-image-in-qweb-report/28628727#28628727)

I hope this should helpful for you ...! :)

Comment: It works if I put image in /my_module/static/src/img/ folder, but doesn't in /my_module/img/ folder.
Only works if I use the filename extension (like png).
Works whithout "class img......"