# How to print images in Custom QWeb reports in Odoo?

Tags: xml, image, report, odoo, qweb

I would like to display images which are uploaded by users in my custom Qweb reports.

Which is the best way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display image in QWeb report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561121/display-image-in-qweb-report)

Comment: Hi this question is not duplicate of that one. There he mentioned about header and footer that i have already done. but when it comes to inserting image in the page. blank image is showing... what to do?? any idea...!! Thanks

Comment: could you plz help me out?

Comment: Hi please refer to this link as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149379/picture-in-odoo-qweb-report                      Can you please provide what code have you done till now ? It would be easier to guide you.

Comment: Do you want to show a picture which is stored in the database or physically saved as a normal file?

Comment: hi , i want to store the picture which is already stored in some records of DB.

Comment: http://localhost:8069/web/binary/image?model=book.room&id=2&field=image&t=1445919360006

Comment: Hello, how to replace image in other field value? /like .png image/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to show an image from the database you can just use the image widget like this:

```xml
<span t-field="o.image_field_name" t-field-options='{"widget": "image"}'/>
```

And if you want to show an image stored as a file:

```xml
<img t-att-src="'/module_name/static/src/img/image_name.png'" />
```

**Note**: respect the order and the type of the quotes

Comment: What is o.product_id is here??

Comment: It is an example, that's the name of your field in the model. I'm going to change it

Comment: I am getting this ERROR:QWebException: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_fields'

Comment: my field name is 'image'... here is the line <p><b> Photo: </b><span t-field="image.image" t-field-options='{"widget": "image"}'/></p>

Comment: The field should be binary type. Are you able to print the rest of fields of the model? You only get the error when you print this field? I can assure you it works fine because I'm doing it like that

Comment: Can you update the question with the code of your report?

Comment: Try with `<span t-field="o.image" t-field-options='{"widget": "image"}'/>`

Comment: Thank you...Its working !! we have to t-field="doc.binary field_name"

Comment: Great answer my friend!

Answer (score 3):

For someone who lands here from Google... For dynamic images from the database, one can use

```
<img t-attf-src="data:image/*;base64,{{o.image_field_name}}"/>
```

...where `o.image_field_name` is a dynamic field from the database/model. I prefer the `<img/>` tag over a `<span/>` for images.

To show a static image, use plain HTML.

```
<img src="path/to/image/file" alt="Alternate Text"/>
```

**Note:** alternate text attribute in an image does **not** add value in PDF reports. They don't show up when the image is missing, as in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to call a function from QWeb and get image.
This code help me to read proper image field and print it with QWeb.

```
    <t t-foreach="get_image(id)" t-as="image_browse">
         <span t-field="image_browse.image" t-field-options='{"widget": "image"}'/> 
</t>
```

image_browse is a browse of id that send by get_image(id)

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr t-foreach="o.pack_operation_ids" t-as="pack_operation">
    <td>
      <span t-field="pack_operation.product_id.image_small" t-field-options='{"widget": "image"}'/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

- QWeb has an iteration directive foreach which take an expression returning the collection to iterate on, and a second parameter t-as providing the name to use for the "current item" of the iteration:
- In `<span>` I access Image of **product_id** using **pack.operation**
- You can select size of image like: image_small and image_medium