# How to include a checkbox image in a Qweb Report?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-9, qweb

Is there way to change checkbox image in qweb report. For example i want to change standard  "V" to image like this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: I don´t understand very well, do you mean in the tree view? If you want to add images to the qweb report check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340909/how-to-print-images-in-custom-qweb-reports-in-odoo#33364315)

Comment: No in Qweb report. i updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 0

Add the file to your module, for example store it in the path `/module_name/static/src/img/image_name.png`

Then now you can add the image to the Qweb Report:

```xml
<img t-att-src="'/module_name/static/src/img/image_name.png'" />
```

**Note**: respect the order and the type of the quotes

### Solution 1

Maybe it is useful to create `ul` html list with all the elements you want to add:

```html
<style>
    .icon_list {
        list-style-image: url('/module_name/static/src/img/image_name.png');
    }
</style>

<!-- [...] -->

<ul class="icon_list" >
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```

(I didn´t try it but it should work as well)

Answer (score 1):

you can simply replace it with the standard Unicode character `☑` by a field that is checking the status

Comment: i want to add a specific image not standard

Comment: no problem add a boolean field to check the status of being checked or not. then if approved draw the image

Comment: you can use t-if as suggested there https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/qweb.html

Comment: is use <input type="checkbox" checked="True" style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;" /> to get original odoo checkbox. but my goal is to replace original image that odoo gives me.(black and white) with my image.

Comment: so you need a css like the following https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Please use "input type as checkbox". It worked for me.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>I agree that glasses are selected based on my indications
```

Comment: Yes it gives me original Odoo checkbox. Black and white. but i want to replace that original checkbox with my image

Answer (score 1):

in **odoo11**
you can choose this class for checkbox

**i class="fa fa-check** which opening and closing tags This gives better checkbox than default in odoo