# Add a static Image in Odoo v10 report

Tags: odoo-10

I am currently trying to add a static image into an Odoo v10 report.
In Odoo v8, I used the image tag with the path like this:

```
<field src="/my_module/static/src/img/my_image.png"/>
```

But in Odoo v10 it does only display an empty rectangle.

Has it been changed in v10 or am I doing something wrong?
The path and the name of the file is correct.

Greetings, Matthias

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561121/how-to-display-an-image-in-a-qweb-report/28628727#28628727

Comment: I've seen this post too. This is exactly what I am doing. I've also tried to add those classes to the field, but with no effect.
EDIT: This also seems to be an Odoo v8 post (The author writes about a openerp.py file). In v8 this method works, but in v10 not.

Comment: This is how I added the image to my report `<img class="img img-responsive" src="/sale/static/img/btn_paynowcc_lg.gif"/>`. I used the link above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all image you want to display is static image not the field so try image tag:

```
<img src="my_module/static/src/img/my_image.png'/>
```

Comment: Would be nice to have more background about why this is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me to display a background image:

```
<div class="page" t-attf-style="background-
image:url('/my_module/static/src/img/my_image.jpg');">
```

Make sure that when you go to (your server's url)/my_module/static/src/img/my_image.jpg in your browser, you can see the image.

So you could do an empty div with your image as background in the place you want your image.