# How to display image in Qweb Report in Odoo10?

Tags: xml, report, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I am beginner for Qweb Report. And i want to display image in Qweb report. So, What should i do for that?

And i also want to know about that what is the difference between '**o.field_name**' and '**docs.field_name**'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to insert a static image in the report you need to have the image in the folder: `your_module/src/img/your_image.jpg`. Then in your report you must insert:

```
<img class="img" src="/your_module/static/src/img/your_image.jpg"/>
```

But if you want to use a field as image you could try this in your report:

```
<img t-attf-src="data:image/*;base64,{{your_image_field}}"/>
```

or

```
<span t-field="o.your_image_field" t-field-options='{"widget": "image"}'/>
```

For more information you could visit: [insert_image_in_qweb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561121/how-to-display-an-image-in-a-qweb-report/28628727#28628727) and [print_image_in_qweb_reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340909/how-to-print-images-in-custom-qweb-reports-in-odoo)

On the other hand, there are some specific variables accessible in reports, `docs` is one of them:

> docs: records for the current report.

So, when you use `docs` you are referring to all the records and when you use `o` (as shown in the following code) you start to iterate for each element:

```
<t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
    <t t-call="..." t-lang="o.partner_id.lang"/>
</t>
```

I hope this help you!

Comment: Thanks Dayana, It's working for <span t-field>. But, for <img t-attf..> image shows as box only. And also how to print any graph or chart?
Thanks for Help.

Comment: I've never print any graph or chat in reports. I'm sorry I can't help you.

Comment: Ok, No problem.

Comment: Hello, How to replace image in other field value, like png image?